# Prestashop 1.6: Upgrade bootstrap files?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, prestashop-1.6

**How do I upgrade the bootstrap-files to current version?**

I saw that the bootstrap-classes were pasted in global.css

Replacing global.css with bootstrap.css doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

There is a bootstrap section in global.css. It is between some initial CSS and the Font Awesome CSS section, you can replace it there. Works fine in Prestashop 1.6.0.6.